# Fetching the last value with a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table (T1) as below in oracle.

```
ReqTimestamp | ReqDuration | ServiceName | Marker
```

The query i am writing is :

```
select max(ReqDuration) from T1 group by ServiceName , Marker;
```

This give me max `ReqDuration` of every `ServiceName,Marker` in my table.

How can i get the value of the `ReqDuration` for the latest `ReqTimestamp` with the above result set.

Any pointers?

Comment: can you give sample data and your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle provides the convenient `keep`/`first` syntax:

```
select max(ReqDuration),
       max(ReqDuration) keep (dense_rank first order by ReqTimeStamp desc)
from T1
group by ServiceName, Marker;
```